# How do I make sure that the file I download has finished?

Tags: c#, file, download, webclient

I have this application which allows me to download certain files from the internet when I press a button.
However.. I have no idea how to make sure that the file has actually finished downloading.

I'm currently using the good old WebClient method of downloading files

```
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(requestUrl), combinedPaths);
    }
```

There is no need to show more of the code really since the download function is very simple and straight forward.
I need to figure out how to keep track of the file that you are downloading to see how much it has downloaded for example 1 / 100%..
I have a very good ISP with 250 Mb/s download speed so its really hard for me to see if it has actually been finished or not.

Comment: [WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) Learn to use Google and MSDN to find these answers on your own. You'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fire `WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted` event and do something with it:

```
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCallback);
```

To know the status of the download you can subscribe to another event handler:

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
```

Answer (score 3):

The WebClient has an event handler called DownlaodFileCompleted that you can use to trigger when the file has finished downloading :

```
myWebClient.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompleted;

public static void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
```

Comment: Ah! Didnt think about the eventhandler! Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure :) @NicoRiff actually beat me to it so he deserves the answered mark.